# backbone 1.1.2, marionette, requirejs, min version

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, gruntjs, marionette

Need help.
https://github.com/serheyShmyg/requirejs-jquery-backbone

This is my boilerplate.
Try install it.
Before install: 
1. change backbone version from 1.1.0 to 1.1.2(latest with amd wrapper); in bower.json.
2. app/jade/layouts/_footer.jade - uncoment Production version, and comment Development.
Like this

```
//-Production
script(src="../js/lib/requirejs/require.js", data-main="../js/main.min.js")
//-Development
//-script(src="../js/lib/requirejs/require.js", data-main="../js/config.js")
```

Install: npm install

Go localhost:8080/markup/ and get in console
Uncaught ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined backbone.marionette.js:35

Can't understand why backbone loading with amd wrapper so long, and marionette can't find Backbone global var.

Its only with backbone 1.1.2 or 1.1.1, this version got AMD wrapper.
And only in min. version of js.

Guys help!
Thank's!

Comment: This question reads as a request to download your application and debug it.

Answer (score 1):

There was a pretty big change made in Backbone from 1.1.0 to 1.1.1: it registers itself as an AMD module (see http://backbonejs.org/#changelog).

To get your optimization working, you probably need to set the `wrapShim` option to true (see http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html).

You can see an example (from my [book on using RequireJS](https://leanpub.com/structuring-backbone-with-requirejs-and-marionette)) here: https://github.com/davidsulc/structuring-backbone-with-requirejs-and-marionette/blob/master/assets/js/build.js#L7